# Unambiguous way to say 'any day within a range of days"?

Tags: ambiguity, dates

What is the unambiguous way to say any day within a range of days? I want to say you can choose any day: 1,2,3,4 or 5th of Aug.

1. You can choose any day between Aug 1st and Aug 5th.
2. You can choose any day from Aug 1st to Aug 5th.
3. You can choose any day within Aug 1st and Aug 5th.

Seems to me that 1 is ambiguous. The person might understand pick one of the two days.

How about options 2 and 3?

Comment: I don't think 1 is ambiguous, at least not in the way you suggest, because of "any day" (you would say "choose either" or something for the other meaning). But it could be ambiguous about whether the 1st and 5th are included, so you could add "inclusive" to make that explicit. 2 is also fine. 3 sounds unnatural to me.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather prefer to say:
You can choose a day between aug 1st and aug 5th. (for the first one)

I think "any" is the main cause of the ambiguity for the first one.

It seems to me that the third is the least ambiguous, although the 2nd sounds clear to me too.

I hope I helped.